# What semantic frameworks are there for computational linguistics?

Tags: computational-linguistics, semantics

Besides Frege's principle of compositionality are there any other philosophical frameworks of language to form distributional semantics in the English language?

Edit - 
Although I'm still yet to complete in full, my doctoral studies involved modelling free association strengths between words. This heavily relied on free association networks collected manually from human subjects. As a means to overcome the extreme cost (both finally and temporally) of creating such networks I sought to form representations / approximations of said networks using geometric representations of words derived through distributional semantics. At the time, Frege's principle was the basis upon which representations were formed. I have since returned to this field of inquiry an in inspection of the standard journals and research outlets I am yet to find an alternative framework upon which distributional semantics can be employed in creating representations for words to be used in linguistic tasks.

I'm unsure whether this is a result of my deficiency in the philosophy of language, so to repeat, are there any other philosophical frameworks to form representations of words using distributional semantics?

Comment: Have you looked into [Wordnet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) and [Framenet](https://framenet.icsi.berkeley.edu/fndrupal/)? They go quite a ways beyond what you're asking for.

Comment: I might have attempted to answer it, but realized I'll have to write *a lot*. Instead, I'll refer you to the canonical textbook, [Speech and Language Processing](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/), specifically, Ch. 18, 19 and Appendix C.

Comment: I think this is too broad. *Any* framework could be used with computational linguistics.

Comment: @curiousdannii - Indeed. I'm interested in investigating as many different frameworks as possible. The area of specific interest is forming mathematical representations of words (via distributional semantics) that can then be used to elicit free association strengths. This currently doesn't exist. There is no background work in it. Hence why I'm forced to ask a broad question. I'm hoping to do a basic inspection of different frameworks to gain an initial idea of what works and what doesn't. 
Does that make sense?

Comment: @prash - That is fantastic. Thanks so much for the link. Yes, it's very broad. Just as a point of reference, this is to be used in eliciting Free Association Strengths between words (primarily the University of South Florida Free Association Norms)

Comment: @DavidGalea I'm not aware of anyone who does mathematical representations of words, but it could exist. I'd suggest editing this to focus on that.

Comment: @curiousdannii - There is a huge field of study into this area. Generally the mathematical representations employed are High Dimensional Real Vectors, Discrete Probability Distributions, Weighted Di-Graphs, and Deep Neural Networks.

Comment: @curiousdannii See [word2vec (or word embeddings)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec). In short, map (somehow) a word to a high dimensional vector such that vector operations (usually just distance) capture something about meaning of the words. Also see [ontologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_(information_science)) for a logical framework (which I consider mathematical).

Comment: @DavidGalea See any intro text on (general, linguistic) semantics. There's Montague grammar, first order logic, programming language semantics where compositionality (lack of side effects) is very important. Look at [wikipedia's article on semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics) for a (very rough) initial guide.

Comment: @Mitch I'd consider that more an analysis than representation, unless it's reversible? Although reading Wikipedia the "Preservation of semantic and syntactic relationships" section notes a result that's comparable to componential analysis, so maybe I could call it a representation.

Comment: @curiousdannii Lots of representations are many to one. It collapses the huge (infinite?) set of concepts into a small (ish? 300?) set of coefficients that are near inscrutable but still a word vector is a representation of a word.

Comment: @Mitch - Thanks for the link and references. Google scholar seems to be a deluge of different attempts with varying success. I'm struggle to find unified patterns withing the enormity of data.

Comment: @Mitch - I'm very familiar with the high dimensions vector approach. So far, it appears that vector representations are fairly limited in construction and use. As it's a fairly new field, this is to be expected - but it would be great to see alternative structures employed (in particular where core axioms of metric spaces are relaxed - i.e. through a lie-algebra).

Comment: @curiousdannii - I should say that when I say 'representation' I mean a pseudo isometric mapping of words to a mathematical structure so that linguistic task can be elicited using properties of the mathematical structure employed. So, in comparing if a word 'a' is more similar to word 'b' than 'c' then we if we translate those words into points in space than we can measure the distance between the points to 'model' (I use that term very loosely) the similarity of the words.

Comment: @curiousdannii - Could you advise what edits you made to my OP?

Comment: @DavidGalea You can see yourself - click "edited yesterday" at the bottom of the post.

Comment: @curiousdannii - Thanks for the info.

Comment: @curiousdannii - Just seeking clarification on the removal of the 'semantics' tag - why did that occur?

Comment: @DavidGalea It wasn't clear to me that it was relevant. I'll add it back.

Comment: @DavidGalea What department is your degree in? (and what is you undergraduate degree subject) We might better know how to direct you knowing you current and past subject coverage.

Comment: @Mitch Bach Maths, Masters IT (by research), PhD Information Science (candidate) - that I abandoned years ago but want to get back into. My previous coverage is a mish mash of geometric representations of words for word similarity tests. I would like to focus on using free association to assist in query expansion in search engines.

Comment: @Mitch - I should mention that I spend a lot of my personal time work in Real Analysis, Abstract Algebra, and Computational Mathematics. I have a soft spot for integral calculus as well ... but it's more of a 'crossword puzzle' styled interest rather then a field of focus.

Comment: Sorry, I'm also spending a lot more time in Probability Theory... which I believe will push me towards Measure Theory fairly soon.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99488/discussion-on-question-by-david-galea-what-semantic-frameworks-are-there-for-com).